# Resetting InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I've been looking at past submissions regarding this and haven't been able to find a solution that seems to work.

I have a simple form that calculates and then increments a value. The innerHTML output ("YourAmount") works fine the first time the form is submitted. However, if I resubmit the form with another amount, the original output flickers the old calculated results with the new one. How do I reset the innerHTML output?

Thanks!

```js
// function for formatting numbers in currency format
function CurrencyFormatted(amount) {
  var i = parseFloat(amount);
  if (isNaN(i)) {
    i = 0.00;
  }
  var minus = '';
  if (i < 0) {
    minus = '-';
  }
  i = Math.abs(i);
  i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
  i = i / 100;
  s = new String(i);
  if (s.indexOf('.') < 0) {
    s += '.00';
  }
  if (s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) {
    s += '0';
  }
  s = minus + s;
  s = CommaFormatted(s)
  return s;
}

// function for formatting numbers with embedded commas
function CommaFormatted(amount) {
  var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
  var a = amount.split('.', 2)
  var d = a[1];
  var i = parseInt(a[0]);
  if (isNaN(i)) {
    return '';
  }
  var minus = '';
  if (i < 0) {
    minus = '-';
  }
  i = Math.abs(i);
  var n = new String(i);
  var a = [];
  while (n.length > 3) {
    var nn = n.substr(n.length - 3);
    a.unshift(nn);
    n = n.substr(0, n.length - 3);
  }
  if (n.length > 0) {
    a.unshift(n);
  }
  n = a.join(delimiter);
  if (d.length < 1) {
    amount = n;
  } else {
    amount = n + '.' + d;
  }
  amount = minus + amount;
  return amount;
}

function calculate() {
  var NumStores = document.getElementById('NumStores').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var baseProfit = NumStores * 50.00;
  result.value = baseProfit;
  var baseProfitOverYear = baseProfit * 360; // base profit (stores x cost) over 360 days
  var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');
  result2.value = baseProfitOverYear;



  var amount = baseProfitOverYear; // load from server
  var delay = 1000; // milliseconds    
  var incAmount = 20; // change to the amount by which you wish to increment
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("YourAmount").innerHTML = "$" + CurrencyFormatted(amount += incAmount);
  }, delay)

}

// disable enter key
$(document).keypress(
  function(event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thisForm">
  <input id="NumStores" type="number" required />
  <input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
</form>
<br><br>
<p id="YourAmount">Your Amount Is 0</p>
```

Comment: You appear to have a few JavaScript errors.

Comment: Where is 'result' and 'result2' elements? Post all needed html

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a span tag within the paragraph tag to hold the value. Then make sure you only have one interval occurring at a time.

```js
// Document elements and variables
var numStores = document.getElementById('num-stores'),
    result = document.getElementById('result-1'),
    result2 = document.getElementById('result-2'),
    yourAmount = document.getElementById('your-amount'),
    intervalId = null; // We need to rember this...

// Constants
var profitMargin = 50.00,
    numberOfDays = 360,
    incAmount = 20, // change to the amount by which you wish to increment
    timerDelay = 1000; // milliseconds    

function calculate() {
  var inputValue = numStores.value;
  var baseProfit = inputValue * profitMargin;
  var baseProfitOverYear = baseProfit * numberOfDays; // base profit (stores x cost) over 360 days
  var amount = baseProfitOverYear; // load from server

  result.value = baseProfit;
  result2.value = baseProfitOverYear;

  clearInterval(intervalId); // Clear the GLOBAL interval, before we start a new one.
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    yourAmount.innerHTML = "$" + CurrencyFormatted(amount += incAmount);
  }, timerDelay);
}

// Disable enter key
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

// function for formatting numbers in currency format
function CurrencyFormatted(amount) {
  var i = parseFloat(amount);
  if (isNaN(i)) {
    i = 0.00;
  }
  var minus = '';
  if (i < 0) {
    minus = '-';
  }
  i = Math.abs(i);
  i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
  i = i / 100;
  s = new String(i);
  if (s.indexOf('.') < 0) {
    s += '.00';
  }
  if (s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) {
    s += '0';
  }
  s = minus + s;
  s = CommaFormatted(s)
  return s;
}

// function for formatting numbers with embedded commas
function CommaFormatted(amount) {
  var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
  var a = amount.split('.', 2)
  var d = a[1];
  var i = parseInt(a[0]);
  if (isNaN(i)) {
    return '';
  }
  var minus = '';
  if (i < 0) {
    minus = '-';
  }
  i = Math.abs(i);
  var n = new String(i);
  var a = [];
  while (n.length > 3) {
    var nn = n.substr(n.length - 3);
    a.unshift(nn);
    n = n.substr(0, n.length - 3);
  }
  if (n.length > 0) {
    a.unshift(n);
  }
  n = a.join(delimiter);
  if (d.length < 1) {
    amount = n;
  } else {
    amount = n + '.' + d;
  }
  amount = minus + amount;
  return amount;
}
```

```css
label { font-weight: bold; }
.input-field { display: block; }
.input-field label { display: inline-block; width: 7.667em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="this-form">
  <label>Number of Stores</label> <input id="num-stores" type="number" required />
  <input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate">
</form>
<br>
<p>Your amount is: <span id="your-amount">$0.00</span></p>

<div class="input-field"><label>Base Profit</label> <input type="text" id="result-1" /></div>
<div class="input-field"><label>Annual Profit</label> <input type="text" id="result-2" /></div>
```

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, thank you for the input. I do appreciate it.

Comment: When I submit a number and the first calculation runs it works as expected. If I enter another amount and click "Calculate" again, I see the flickering between the two results. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: I fixed it, you need to REMEMBER the ID so that only ONE interval can occur at a time.

Comment: I see. Still learning this stuff. This is organized a lot more efficiently than before. Thank you so much for the assist.